# Does IntelliJ remote Javascript debug configuration allow for the cache busting?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, browser-cache

I know how to bust the cache from javascript - adding a dynamically generated dummy query parameter to the URL. However, I am debugging my web app from the IntelliJ IDE using Remote Javascript Debug configuration. I do not see how can I utilize this technique there.

The problem is that chrome caches the html page of my app and I have to clear the cache manually all the time - drives me nuts.

I tried adding a static query parameter like "?bla=bla" - no dice. Chrome still caches it.

The Chrome does have an option to disable the caching - [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development), but it only works if the debugging tools panel is open - not good.

So, what is the way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: See the related request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-54322. Did you try it with incognito mode?

Comment: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464 says nothing about pages not being cached in the incognito mode. Supposing they are not cached indeed, then yes, this issue addresses my problem too.